# PostgreSQL Trim excessive trailing zeroes: type numeric but expression is of type text

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to clean out excessive trailing zeros, I used the following query...

```
UPDATE _table_ SET _column_=trim(trailing '00' FROM '_column_');
```

...and I received the following error:

> ERROR:  column "_column_" is of 
>   expression is of type text.

I've played around with the quotes since that usually is what it barrels down to for text versus numeric though without any luck.

The `CREATE TABLE` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE _table_ (
 id bigint NOT NULL,
 x bigint,
 y bigint,
 _column_ numeric
);
```

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for `_table_`

Comment: Aside: Unconditional `UPDATE` is often needlessly expensive. Add a `WHERE` clause to only update rows that actually change. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cast the arguments from and the result back to numeric:

```
UPDATE _table_ SET _column_=trim(trailing '00' FROM _column_::text)::numeric;
```

Also note that you don't quote column names with single quotes as you did.

Comment: This happens to me a lot - people beating me by 20 seconds or so.  :)  Upvoting, obviously.

Comment: @rchang: harmic also explains the primary cause of the error: invalid quoting.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter True enough.  I was just now thinking that without the explicit cast of the `trim` result back to `numeric` there may have been another error, but I got past my brain fart and realized the implicit conversion would work as long as the resulting string looks reasonably like a number.

Comment: Another good question (though not necessary for me right now) is how to keep everything to the hundredth value (keeping 1.00 when the value is 1.00 to begin with). Thanks!

Comment: @John: Don't put new questions into comments, please. Ask a new question. Basically: `round(_column_, 2)`.

Comment: Careful with this answer. It will convert `100` into `1`!

Comment: As @NicoBurns pointed out, this doesn't just remove trailing zeros from after the decimal point. Which is not ideal in a lot of scenarios!

Answer (score 7):

Postgres version 13 now comes with the `trim_scale()` function:

```sql
UPDATE _table_ SET _column_ = trim_scale(_column_);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another (arguably more consistent) way to clean out the trailing zeroes from a `NUMERIC` field would be to use something like the following:

```
UPDATE _table_ SET _column_ = CAST(to_char(_column_, 'FM999999999990.999999') AS NUMERIC);
```

Note that you would have to modify the `FM` pattern to match the maximum expected `precision` and `scale` of your `_column_` field. For more details on the `FM` pattern modifier and/or the `to_char(..)` function see the PostgreSQL docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE).

Edit: Also, see [the following](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnumed-devel/2012-09/msg00017.html) post on the `gnumed-devel` mailing list for a longer and more thorough explanation on this approach.

Comment: stumbled across this question when trying to remove trailing zeros from after the decimal point (ie 123.1200 -> 123.12) and this answer works perfectly for me (whilst not effecting numbers such as 1200) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`trim` takes string parameters, so `_column_` has to be cast to a string (`varchar` for example).  Then, the result of `trim` has to be cast back to `numeric`.

```
UPDATE _table_ SET _column_=trim(trailing '00' FROM _column_::varchar)::numeric;
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with all the answers here. Although this looks like a simple problem, it's not.

If you have pg 13 or higher, you should use trim_scale (there is an answer about that already). If not, here is my "Polyfill":

```
DO $x$
BEGIN
IF count(*)=0 FROM pg_proc where proname='trim_scale' THEN
CREATE FUNCTION trim_scale(numeric) RETURNS numeric AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN trim($1::text, '0') = '.' THEN 0 WHEN trim($1::text, '0')::numeric = $1 THEN trim($1::text, '0')::numeric ELSE $1 END $$
LANGUAGE SQL;
END IF;
END;
$x$;
```

And here is a query for testing the answers:

```
WITH test as (SELECT unnest(string_to_array('1|2.0|0030.00|4.123456000|300000|0.00','|'))::numeric _column_)
SELECT _column_ original,
trim(trailing '00' FROM _column_::text)::numeric accepted_answer,
CAST(to_char(_column_, 'FM999999999990.999') AS NUMERIC) another_fancy_one,
CASE WHEN trim(_column_::text, '0') = '.' THEN 0 WHEN trim(_column_::text, '0')::numeric = _column_  THEN trim(_column_::text, '0')::numeric ELSE _column_ END my,
trim_scale(_column_) as the_actual_function FROM test;
```

Well... it looks like, I'm trying to show the flaws of the earlier answers, while just can't come up with other testcases. Maybe you should write more, if you can.

I'm like short syntax instead of fancy sql keywords, so I always go with :: over `CAST` and function call with comma separated args over constructs like `trim(trailing '00' FROM _column_)`. But it's a personal taste only, you should check your company or team standards (and fight for change them XD)

Comment: The suggested solution above didn't work for me for the the test case `trim_scale(0.0::numeric)` in Postgres 12 and fails with `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "."`. Swapping to use `rtrim` instead of `trim` fixed it for me.

Comment: Good catch, ty. Fixed with a tiny edit. (Although replace all `trim` to `rtrim` also would do)  As i used to say to my students: it was intentional. (it wasn't)